# Ripple effect with attribute selectableItemBackgroundBorderless not working with Android 13 and newer

Tags: android, ripple-effect

I want to add Ripple Effect to a view but it seems not working when I added

> android:background=”?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless”

and it is working as usual  when I added

> android:background=”?android:attr/selectableItemBackground”

It works with android 12 and older but not work with android 13 and newer.
With android 13 and newer only `android:background=”?android:attr/selectableItemBackground”` is working, But I want the Ripple behavior of `android:background=”?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless”`.

Please help.

Thanks You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `android:background="?android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`
instead of `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`